# Passing data to a Fragment in part of a tabbed FragmentActivity after coming back from another startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I'm trying to follow [this idea for tabs with fragments](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) to have a FragmentActivity hosting two Fragment tabs. In addition, I have a button on the FragmentActivity that calls startActivityForResult() on an Activity to add an item to one of the child Fragment tabs.

The problem is, when the Activity is finished, the callback onActivityResult() code on the FragmentActivity is throwing a

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras)
>   }} to activity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this
>   action after onSaveInstanceState."

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            MyData d = data.getParcelableExtra("data");

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (fm.findFragmentByTag(id) == null) {
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.<my_container>, new MyFragment(), id)
                            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
            MyFragment f = (MyFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(id); 
            f.addData(d);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that f is null after calling fm.findFragmentByTag(id) the second time. I also tried calling mTabsAdapter.getItem(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()); but that returns a Fragment with the ArrayAdapter inside of it being null.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what. Could some please explain to me how should I approach this scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is how I solved this, in case someone runs into something similar.

Originally I was calling startActivityForResult() from the FragmentActivity hosting the tabs, not from one of the Fragment classes being "tabbed". So now first I add the menu item to the action bar from the Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_rule, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_new) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);

        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Three things to note here: 1) the method signature is different than the one of an Activity, override the appropriate method for the Fragment; 2) you have to call super.onCreateOptionsMenu at the end; and 3) you have to add setHasOptionsMenu(true); to the onAttach call of the Fragment.

Next, implement your return code normally on the method onActivityResult(...) of the Fragment. The only difference is that you have to also override the method on the hosting FragmentActivity and call the super there. This is to ensure that Fragment.onActivityResult gets called.

After this transfer of logic from the FragmentActivity to the Fragment, everything works perfectly.